# No funcionan características de paginas incrustadas con iframe

Tags: html, iframe

incruste una pagina externa pero no tiene todas sus funciones

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://mapa.satelitec.mx/mtz-limon/"></iframe>
```

si entran en la pagina incrustada incluye geolocalización en tiempo real pero al incrustarla nada de eso ni sus iconos funcionan

Comment: buenas. SI le doy a ejectutar, funciona. O vos te refieres a que no funciona algo en particular?

Comment: Si, la pagina tiene un botón de geolocalización, si entras a la [pagina](https://mapa.satelitec.mx/mtz-limon/) se ven incluso sus iconos y tiene uno que te ubica en tiempo real

Comment: Ok, te comento abajo

Answer (score 0):

Pas que la web de ellos esta mal configurada, las requests de las fuentes (woff2), que deben ser las que cargan los iconos, estan siendo bloqueadas por politicas CORS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas formas no pierde funcionalidad, si cliqueo en los botones, sigue interacutando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

---

PD: Podes reclamarles, ya que es tema de ellos en realidad.

Comment: Se puede configurar eso en el host para activar esas funcionalidades? La función que me interesaba más era la de georreferenciación

Comment: Osea es una configuracion que tienen que ralizar los dueños del host mapa.satelitec.mx.  Desde tu lado no vas a poder hacer nada.

Comment: Yo soy el dueño del host pero apenas estoy empezando con pruebas XD

Comment: Entonces es asi, vas a tener que configurar desde el host, las politicas CORS, para que cuando alguien embeba tu web, no le pase eso con las tipografias.

Comment: Listo, ya me permite ver los iconos pero sigue sin activar el botón de geolocalizacion

Comment: Eso es por que los permisos del iframe no estan siendo solicitados. Vas a tener que ver como pedis permisos al GPS, dede la web que embebe tu aplicativo.